# Reduce data size for a plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I need to plot large oscilloscope data sets. They are too large (**100 million** Values) to plot all of them in a `for loop`. If I try to do that it results in a `MemoryError`. So with the help of Stackoverflow I came up with a solution that isn't pretty but it works.

Original Dataset:
[image]

To reduce the amount of data to be plotted I can remove all rows of the dataset, that have a `y-value` between `1` and `-1`. This can be done comfortably with pandas:

`df` is the dataset in form of a `pandas.DataFrame()`.

`df[1]` is the column which is to be examined.

This results in:
[image]

This reduces the length of the dataset from **100 million** to about **200 thousand**. My Question is: Is there a way to reduce data length and keep its original look (prevent the ugly cut-off)?

Comment: Though I'm not sure why you would plot your data with a for loop, you can reduce the length of the dataset by, say resampling with mean.

Comment: How else would you make a program work, that is supposed to analyze many datasets and save the plot result?

Comment: "(prevent the ugly cut-off)" <- I'm not sure what you mean by that; if you're referring to the dense, blue, more-or-less-horizontal line in your plot, then that's due to the fact you've arbitrarily chosen `1` as a y-axis cutoff, whereas it's likely a little bit higher than that. Consider plotting a histogram (`plt.hist(df[1])`, try to find a *good* bin width!) to evaluate your threshold.